# Unable to install wordpress - white plank appear on installation page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I need to insatll wordpress on the server, I uploaded the files on wordpress int "new1" folder inside public_html folder. but a white blank appear on

```
http://www.pichuberry.net/new1/wp-admin/install.php
```

I make this .htaccess file and upload it inside public_html folder but still doesn't work!

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I rename the themes and plugin folder and still doesn't work.

I delete the whole wordpress folders and upload them again and still same problem!

please help!

**Edit**
I turn on the debugging mode and found this error

```
 PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$search' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in /home/pichu/web/pichuberry.net/public_html/new1/wp-includes/query.php on line 1705
```

Comment: This isn't a WordPress issue, it's likely an Apache or Nginx issue...or a permissions issue

Comment: What do you think it could be?

Comment: Oh, the white screen of death. Fatal errors in your PHP.

Comment: Are you using any custom theme or the in built wordpress theme? And also try to install wordpress without any plugins that you might have used.

Comment: Default themes and also I renamed the plugin folder so wordpress will not see them!

Comment: Can you please download a fresh wordpress and try to install that and see whether it is getting installed or not? If it gets installed, then your current wordpress has problem. If not then it might be something to do with the server configuration.